# How to tap into the background image, so I could change it based on the switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I would like the app to change the background image depending on the conditions in my `switch` statement. Now I don't know how to tap into the background image for it to change when for example the `case` is between `801...804` it will not only `return "cloud.bolt"` but also an image that I have in my assets. Here is the code:

```
var conditionName: String {
    switch conditionId {
    case 200...232:
        return "cloud.bolt"
    case 300...321:
        return "cloud.drizzle"
    case 500...531:
        return "cloud.rain"
    case 600...622:
        return "cloud.snow"
    case 701...781:
        return "cloud.fog"
    case 800:
        return "sun.max"
    case 801...804:
        return "cloud.bolt"
    default:
        return "cloud"

    }
}
```

Comment: Is a background image shown in some `UIImageView` ?

Comment: I don’t think so. I mean I have only added some image through the main storyboard. At the moment I’m actually away from home so I don’t see my code but I will update tomorrow and give you better picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. If name of the image assets is same as the string you are returning in your `conditionName`, you don't need to `return` an image. You can simply set it as backgroundImageView's image using [`init(named:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init) initializer:

```
backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: conditionName)
```

***OR***

Option 2. However, if you **need** to return a string as well as an image you can simply change your variable's type to a [Tuple Type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID448) `(String, UIImage?)`:

```
var conditionName: (String, UIImage?) {
    switch conditionId {
    case 200...232:
        return ("cloud.bolt", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    case 300...321:
        return ("cloud.drizzle", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    case 500...531:
        return ("cloud.rain", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    case 600...622:
        return ("cloud.snow", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    case 701...781:
        return ("cloud.fog", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    case 800:
        return ("sun.max", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    case 801...804:
        return ("cloud.bolt", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))
    default:
        return ("cloud", UIImage(named: "someimagename"))

    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but now I got this: [link](https://snipboard.io/yGeJ9Q.jpg)

Comment: No wait, you are doing botht the thisngs in my answer. You need to do either point 1 or 2. You dont need a tuple if you are going to use the returned string. May be i did not make the distinction in my answer clear enough. I have updated the answer now, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're wanting or if it can be improved (I'm completely new to programming) but here goes...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var conditionName = String()

    var imageView: UIImageView!
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.center = view.center
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)


    func assignBackground() {
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }


    func changeBackground(condition: Int) {

        switch condition {
        case 200...232:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img1")
            conditionName = "cloud.bolt"
        case 300...321:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img2")
            conditionName = "cloud.drizzle"
        case 500...531:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img3")
            conditionName = "cloud.rain"
        case 600...622:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img4")
            conditionName = "cloud.snow"
        case 701...781:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img5")
            conditionName = "cloud.fog"
        case 800:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img6")
            conditionName = "sun.max"
        case 801...804:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img7")
            conditionName = "cloud.bolt"
        default:
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img8")
            conditionName = "cloud"
        }
        assignBackground()
    }

    changeBackground(condition: 500)
}
```